# How do I rerun a method in the same method?

Tags: c#

As the title states, how do I rerun a method again inside the same method without having an error called StackOverflowException was unhandled?
(Where I put the asterisks is where the problem derives from. "Random rnd = new Random();" is then highlighted in green saying that error.)

```
private void AI()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int aimove = rnd.Next(0, 7);
        CheckIfValid();
        if (aimove == 0 && cc0 == false || aimove == 1 && cc1 == false || aimove == 2 && cc2 == false || aimove == 3 && cc3 == false || 
            aimove == 4 && cc4 == false || aimove == 5 && cc5 == false || aimove == 6 && cc6 == false)
        {
            **AI();**
        }
        else if (aimove == 0 && cc0 == true || aimove == 1 && cc1 == true || aimove == 2 && cc2 == true || aimove == 3 && cc3 == true ||
            aimove == 4 && cc4 == true || aimove == 5 && cc5 == true || aimove == 6 && cc6 == true)
        {
            if (aimove == 0)
            {
                c0++;
                Drop(0);
            }
            else if (aimove == 1)
            {
                c1++;
                Drop(1);
            }
            else if (aimove == 2)
            {
                c2++;
                Drop(2);
            }
            else if (aimove == 3)
            {
                c3++;
                Drop(3);
            }
            else if (aimove == 4)
            {
                c4++;
                Drop(4);
            }
            else if (aimove == 5)
            {
                c5++;
                Drop(5);
            }
            else if (aimove == 6)
            {
                c6++;
                Drop(6);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: look up recursion - you need an exit condition

Comment: So where would I put the exit condition?

Comment: Have you stepped through your method with a debugger?  Is it doing what you expect?  Where is the observed behavior of your method differing from your expected behavior?  You can absolutely call a method from inside itself just like you've done - you just can't do it forever.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: variable names like `c0` and `cc0` don't shed any light at all on what this code is trying to do, and you aren't showing when these variables are changing from true to false in this snippet, so it's really not possible for us to know when the loop is supposed to end.

Comment: Arrays my friend, learn about arrays.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: I don't know if you're looking at the same code... it's not the `Drop()` call that is recursive.

Comment: Why not `Drop(aimove);` instead of hard coding all the values. It seems inflexible and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

If AI() calls itself again, then the ccX bool associated with aimove's value is currently false.

Chances are cc1 - cc6 are all set to false and thus AI() will always call itself, creating new instances of Random until you get a stack overflow.

You need to add an exit condition that sets your cc1-cc6 booleans to true so the recursion chain will end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I would start on this: simplify the code to make it easier to reason about.

There are a few things that we can do.

Starting with the `if` statement, we can do this:

```
var ccs = new [] { cc0, cc1, cc2, cc3, cc4, cc5, cc6 };
if (ccs[aimove] == false)
{
    AI();
}
```

The `else if` condition is just the logical negation of the first condition, so we can replace with just an `else`.

Each `if` inside the else is doing much the same thing. We can simplify this using a dictionary.

So the code can become this:

```
private void AI()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int aimove = rnd.Next(0, 7);
    CheckIfValid();

    var ccs = new [] { cc0, cc1, cc2, cc3, cc4, cc5, cc6 };

    var increments = new Dictionary<int, Action>()
    {
        { 0, () => c0++ },
        { 1, () => c1++ },
        { 2, () => c2++ },
        { 3, () => c3++ },
        { 4, () => c4++ },
        { 5, () => c5++ },
        { 6, () => c6++ },
    };

    if (ccs[aimove] == false)
    {
        AI();
    }
    else
    {
        increments[aimove]();
        Drop(aimove);
    }
}
```

Now, this is still a bit messy. It would be nice to redefine `cc0` .. `cc6` and `c0` ... `c6` as arrays, like so:

```
private int[] cs = new int[7];
private bool[] ccs = new bool[7];
```

Then, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
private void AI()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int aimove = rnd.Next(0, 7);
    CheckIfValid();
    if (ccs[aimove] == false)
    {
        AI();
    }
    else
    {
        cs[aimove]++;
        Drop(aimove);
    }
}
```

Now the problem *could* come from the fact that all of the `ccs` values are false and no matter what the value of `aimove` is that the code will loop infinitely.

So let's put a check in there.

```
private void AI()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int aimove = rnd.Next(0, 7);
    CheckIfValid();
    if (ccs.All(cc => cc == false))
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("All `ccs` are false");
    }
    if (ccs[aimove] == false)
    {
        AI();
    }
    else
    {
        cs[aimove]++;
        Drop(aimove);
    }
}
```

Now if all of the `ccs` are false then the exception will fire and you know your code will blow the stack.

The other issue, which will also cause you grief, and probably will blow the stack even if some of the `ccs` are true, is the fact that you are creating a new `Random` instance for each call to `AI`. The problem with this is that it will be instantiated with the same seed in most calls since the calls are made so rapidly. If it is the same seed then the same values will come out for the call to `rnd.Next(0, 7)`. If each recursive call to `AI` has the same `aimove` value then that could rapidly blow the stack too.

The trick is to make only one instance of `Random` and simply re-use.

So change the code to be like this:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

private void AI()
{
    int aimove = rnd.Next(0, 7);
    CheckIfValid();
    if (ccs.All(cc => cc == false))
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("All `ccs` are false");
    }
    if (ccs[aimove] == false)
    {
        AI();
    }
    else
    {
        cs[aimove]++;
        Drop(aimove);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this fixes it.

I suspect, though, what you're really trying to do is select a valid `aimove` and if you pick an invalid one you are doing a recursive call to `AI` to pick a different one.

Try this instead:

```
private void AI()
{
    if (ccs.All(cc => cc == false))
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("All `ccs` are false");
    }
    int aimove = -1;
    do
    {
        aimove = rnd.Next(0, 7);
        CheckIfValid();
    } while (ccs[aimove] == false);
    cs[aimove]++;
    Drop(aimove);
}
```

Here it just loops within the `AI` method until it picks a valid move.

Another final option is to just select a valid move directly using LINQ.

```
private void AI()
{
    var aimove =
        ccs
            .Select((cc, n) => new { cc, n })
            .Where(x => x.cc)
            .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
            .Select(x => x.n)
            .First();
    cs[aimove]++;
    Drop(aimove);
}
```

Here the `.First()` will throw an exception if there aren't any valid moves. I don't know what `CheckIfValid();` is doing so I didn't know where to put it in.